# Pyinstaller throwing error about ctk but not tk

Tags: python, tkinter, pyinstaller, customtkinter

I've created a GUI with CTk ([Github](https://github.com/TomSchimansky/CustomTkinter)) and a other one with basic Tk ([Tk Python Docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.html)). I tried to convert both to .exe with pyinstaller, but the CTk one didn't work, it only threw this error quickly and exit:

```
gui.exe
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "customtkinter\__init__.py", line 20, in <module>
  File "customtkinter\theme_manager.py", line 16, in load_theme
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\Heikki\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\_MEI117522\\customtkinter\\assets\\themes\\blue.json'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "GUI.py", line 8, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 499, in exec_module
  File "customtkinter\__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\Heikki\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\_MEI117522\\customtkinter\\assets\\themes\\blue.json'

The .json theme file for CustomTkinter could not be found.
If packaging with pyinstaller was used, have a look at the wiki:
https://github.com/TomSchimansky/CustomTkinter/wiki/Packaging#windows-pyinstaller-auto-py-to-exe
[9004] Failed to execute script 'GUI' due to unhandled exception!
```

I **kind of** see the problem here (by reading the error message), but Im not familiar with GUIs, what should I do?

Pyinstaller command:

```
pyinstaller --onefile GUI.py
```

Comment: Add `--collect-data customtkinter` when running `pyinstaller`.

Comment: @acw1668 Sorry for this really late reply, but thank you, it worked. Do you know a way for me to set a tkinter iconbitmap, and still be able to convert to exe and use on other computer. The problem is, it has it in the code, so that you need to have the icon in order to run it.

Comment: You can include the icon file in the exe by using `--add-data` option of `pyinstaller`.